Number of samples from an urn that is fraction $f$ of black balls to have probability $p$ of selecting one
I have two ways of interpreting a 'cost' for some event that occurs a fraction $f$ of the time. The first way is the coding length under the Shannon-Fano encoding, giving $-\log{f}$. The second way is as some function of the number of times you need to sample before that event occurs. I was expecting the two ways to roughly agree. I wonder if there is some interpretation of the number of samples needed that depends on $\log f$.
The expected number of samples before the event occurs doesn't work, it is $\frac{1}{f}$. Taking the number of samples before a certain probability threshold is exceeded looks more promising. For example, if I ask how many times, in terms of $f$, do I need to sample before the event has a 50% chance of occurring at least once, then, letting $c$ denote the cost, I get
$(1-f)^c = 0.5\,. \\$
However, this seems to simplify as
$c = \frac{\log{0.5}}{\log{1-f}} = \frac{-1}{\log{1-f}}\,.$
Is there any way to quantify how similar this is to $-\log f$ in $[0,1]$? From graphing them, they look quite different.

Unless you are taking logarithms base $~2,~$ the logarithm of $~(0.5) \neq -1.$

Well yes I'm thinking base 2, but we could also just select a different threshold of $1/e$

I suggest that you edit your posting to describe the specific logarithm base that you with to explore.  Base 2 seems like an elegant approach.   Then, you simply have to recognize that $$\log_2 (1-f) = \log_e (1-f) \times \log_2 (e) = \frac{\log_e(1-f)}{\log_e(2)}.$$
